# How to disable UAC programmatically to install a program by LE installshield for all users

Tags: installshield, uac

I have an installation setup created by LE instalshield under VS2012. This setup.exe installs the application, registers some DLLs and activeX files and adds some registry entries as pointers to the location of an SQL server database. This application is to be run by all the users in a group policy created by the IT of their institution. The installation is done under the full administration privileges.

If the UAC of the win 7 is not fully lowered, some DLLs and OCXs are not registered (although the required registry keys are written in the MACHINE area of the registry without any problem!). So in order to avoid this I have to manually lower the UAC to its lowest level before running the Setup.exe. This solves the problem with the registration of DLLs.

But sometimes even though the installed program works for the installed login, it does not work for other logins within the same group/users. So how can I create a setup.exe under LEinstallshield that would 1) not require manual lowering of UAC, 2) install for all users under the same group policy?

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be asking why your installer isn't compatible with UAC instead of asking how to disable UAC.  If you are authoring a clean MSI using the registry tables (COM extraction) instead of using COM self-reg or other custom actions, it should just work.